# Is the performance of Vertx event bus as good or better than ConcurrentQueues in Java?

Tags: java, vert.x

In a project of mine, I decided to use Vertx for the HTTP APIs, given its proven performance record. Then, because the application does use event queues internally I started wondering if I should use [Vertx event bus](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus) and verticles, instead of using my usual [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). I am still quite new to Vertx so I don't know how suitable it could be. I've experience with Akka and Actors and those would fit the bill very well, but I'm not sure if Vertx event bus is designed to scale to 100k events per second?

Answer (score 3):

I work with Vert.x since version 3 and have done some projects with it (It's my main stack, since a couple of years). I did never run into a situation where the event bus was the limiting factor. The event bus is designed to handle such an amount of event and even much more. As @injecteer mentioned, the limiting factor is basically the hardware and how many events will be processed depends on what do you with them and how you scale your code.

Vert.x follows consequently a non-blocking programming model and you should follow it as well ... never be blocking. Vert.x has the concept of loose coupling, that's solved with portioning of the code with "verticles" https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles. You can deploy/start multiple instances of those verticles (your pieces of code). A further base concept is event loop threads (default count of cores * 2).

Each deployed verticle instance will run on a specific event loop thread, and ALL registered handlers (event bus, http server, etc.) are get called on this specific event loop thread at any time. This way you are able to scale your code in a "per thread" fashion, according to your needs. Events over the event bus are distributed with round robin between the verticle instance (and the handlers within the verticles) ... btw handlers of http requests are also distributed with round robin.

Clustered mode is a bit different. How do you (de)serialize dtos (Json, Protobuf, etc.) can become a significant difference in terms of performance. A clustered event bus has TCP sockets between all nodes, means events are sent point-to-point. The cluster manager (Hazelcast is the default) on the other hand defines to which node an event should get send to (round robin on cluster level), but events are NOT sent over the cluster manager. E.g. the cluster manager knows which node has consumers registered on the event bus (on which address).

Since Vert.x 4 milestone 5 the cluster manager SPI provides an entry point where you can implement your own alternative to round robin, e.g. load specific distribution etc.

There are some basic concepts like event loop threads, non-blocking programming, and verticles (which is not mandatory but recommended). If / when those concepts are clear you get a very flexible base for near any kind of application. I personally love it and also did never see any other framework/technology that reaches near a comparable performance (with a proper scaling that fit the load).

Answer (score 1):

I benchmarked Vert.x event bus (using pure Vert.x for pub and sub) and found it to max out at around 100K msg/s / CPU (using high-end Xeon CPU). Interestingly the performance was comparable to Vert.x's WebSockets implementation so I agree it's not the bottleneck if you do:

WS -> Event Bus

But if you do 10 hops on the Event Bus then it could be the bottleneck.

I observed the performance of the [LMAX Disrupter](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Performance-Results) to be much higher but once you introduce I/O then the I/O become the bottleneck with Disrupter. The problem with disrupter is that you can't use it with Netty.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding all libraries running in a single JVM would have comparable performance levels and are limited by your hardware and settings.
So, local event-bus would perform as good as any other local tech.

The things start getting interesting, if you scale up your system across different JVMs and/or different machines. This is where Vert.x EB shines, as you don't have to change the code of your verticles!

You replace the local EB with clustered one, which is a matter of adding dependencies and configuring the cluster, but still no original code for event-bus operations has to be changed. The other way around also works just fine, if you want to squeese several verticles into the same JVM.

Clustering of the EB of course has it's price, but it's performance has to do rather with underlying clustering technologies like Hazelcast (default) or Infinispan than with Vert.x itself.